# Access JDBC methods from another class within the same package

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a `database` class which imports `java.sql.*` and have following variables

```
Connection connect;
PreparedStatement statement;
ResultSet result;
public database() {} //constructor to connect to db [successful connection]
```

Now I create its instance in another class `database db = new database();`, and I have to do something like this:

```
statement = connect.statement("sql query");
```

But to do this in another class, I have to do it like this:

```
db.statement = db.connect.db.statement("sql query");
```

It is showing error as well as it looks weird.

I think the possible solution could be to create local variables in another class

```
Connection connect = db.connect;
PreparedStatement statement = db.statement;
```

Which makes the `database` a useless class.

Comment: use Connection Pool. Have a look at Design Patterns if you want more flexible customized solution.

Comment: Make database a private class if not being used anywhere else or rather pass a query to a database method. Which will do all the work related to jdbc and return you the result

Comment: @SacJn yes you are correct but i have to pass variable query per connection. if i create `query` method that will return` resultset` then i have to create multiple connections per query

Comment: Yes passing only a query variable will provide you flexibility call that method from anywhere you want. Is there any problem you see passing query String ?

Comment: i have suppose one condition when i have to `select` then accordingly `update` or `insert` and in another condition i have to just insert ..

Comment: Please note it is `prepared statement` .. so i have to pass variables also..

Comment: Yes you will have to pass variables also. But regarding **`insert`**, **`update`** or **`select`** , it will be your query **`string`** that will be constructed as per your requirement. Anyway this is just a direction. Can't tell you exact solution without knowing your full scenario or looking at your code.

Comment: @SacJn i understand what you are telling me.. but i cannot do it that way..

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Use a `java.sql.DataSource` (with or without a connection pool built-in) to obtain a connection. For all the other things a `java.sql.Connection` already has everything you need.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am very new to java. thanks for advice i will look into datasource..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a misunderstanding in my approach

```
statement = connect.statement("sql query"); <--wrong statement

statement = connect.prepareStatement("sql query"); <--correct statement
```

so in another class it should be

```
db.statement = db.connect.prepareStatement("sql query");  <--worked perfectly
```